# Can I compare an array with 2 more arrays and see if it will meet the condition

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, struct

I wanted to ask if its possible to have 1 array with two conditions for it to meet?

```
 lets just say the arrays are

//gi.move2[10] = 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1 
//gi.move3[10] = 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1 
//pi.move1 [10] = 2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8,1,8

scanf("%d",&pi.move1[k]); // user will input 8 thus resulting a &pi.move[7] = 8

     for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
               
               

                if (pi.move1[7] = (gi.move2[7] == '0' || gi.move3[7] == '0'))
                {
                    printf("x");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("-");
                }

            }
```

I tied the code above, but

I have the structure of gi.move2, gi. move3 and pi.move 1// I have no problems with those.

I am not sure how to show that this statement is true
(pi.move1[7] = (gi.move2[7] == '0' || gi.move3[7] == '0'))

I tried this also didnt work.
if (pi.move1[7] = (gi.move2[7] == 0 || gi.move3[7] == 0))
it gave me xxxx-xxxxx-xx
**
The outcome I'm looking for is
--------X--

and also once 8 has been input it cant be used again.
**

the outcome i get is ----------

Thank you

Comment: `how to show that this statement is true (pi.move1[7] = (gi.move2[7] == '0' || gi.move3[7] == '0'))` ...... `gi.move2[7] == '0'` evaluates to always false because `0` is not same as `'0'` ... same with the other evaluation ... then `pi.move1[7]` will be set to `false`

Comment: i did what you said and did this  if (pi.move1[7] = (gi.move2[7] == 0 || gi.move3[7] == 0)) it is now give me xxx-xxx-xxxxx

Comment: `The outcome I'm looking for is --------X--` ... how does the outcome relate to the three arrays? ... you did not explain what you are trying to do ... showing non-working code does not tell us what correctly working code is

Comment: Try `&&` not `||`?

Comment: your code could not have possibly output `xxxx-xxxxx-xx`, which means that you are providing false information in your post ... downvoting

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pi.move1[7] = (gi.move2[7] == '0' || gi.move3[7] == '0'))
```

the single '=' is the first problem i see
try fixing the if logic

Comment: I did try this but it still didn't work